# Musixtex lacking rinforzando notation?

Tags: musixtex

Does Musixtex really not have a command to write rinforzando (rfz)? I've searched through their guide https://icking-music-archive.org/software/musixtex/musixdoc.pdf but haven't found it, not even in the index. Is it really not in the package?

Answer (score 7):

You can define it, based on similar definitions. Changing an example from the manual and adding the definition:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixps}

\makeatletter
\def\rfz{{\ppff r\p@kern f\f@kern z}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{music}\nostartrule
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{12}8}
\startextract
\Notes\ccharnote{-8}{\rfz}\Icresc0{-7}6\ca{bdegh'bde}\en
\Notes\Tcresc0{-4}{-2}\zcharnote{-5}{\fff}\ca{'f}\en
\zendextract
\end{music}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might prefer

```
\def\rfz{{\ppff rf\f@kern z}}
```

that gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you just need a rfz once in a piece, you can simply write a
`{\bi rfz}` within `\notes … \en`, which I have done in the first case. In the second case I have defined it as egreg did, but by using `\bi` and kern the letters by points:

```
\def\rfz{{\bi r\kern-0.5pt f\kern-0.7pt z}}% The kerning in tenths of point is a matter of personal taste

\notes\qqsk\ccharnote{-4}{\bi rfz}\qu f\qu g\bsk\hsk\en\bar%
\notes\ccharnote{-4}{\rfz}\qu h\ql j\ql k\ql j\hbsk\en\bar%
```

[image: examples rfz: not kerned and kerned]